# How to disable React's "Warning: Unknown prop"?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I want to use a self-defined prop for testing and I call it "dataHook", when using it I am getting this warning.

Example code:

```
<div dataHook="header-title">test me</div>
```

on run time I will get this:

```
Warning: Unknown prop `dataHook` on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
    in div (created by GBT)
```

I understand why the warning shows, but I know the circumstances and this code is completely fine with me, how to disable that?

Answer (score 4):

`dataHook` is not a valid property which the `div` element accepts. If you want to use a HTML5 data-* attribute, you need to hyphenate it:

```html
<div data-hook="header-title">...</div>
```

> In React, all DOM properties and attributes (including event handlers) should be camelCased. For example, the HTML attribute tabindex corresponds to the attribute tabIndex in React. **The exception is aria-* and data-* attributes, which should be lowercased.**
>
> — [React's documentation on DOM Elements](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)

Or alternatively you can create your own custom component which returns a `div` element:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.component {
  render() {
    const { children, dataHook } = this.props;

    // do something with the custom property

    return <div>{children}</div>
  }
}

...

<MyComponent dataHook="header-title">...</MyComponent>
```